# Why does read() not succeed until after the process is killed?

Tags: c, unix, pipe, dup2, execl

I'm working on a project that allows a UNIX system to communicate with another machine via a serial connection using cu(1.07).

The following is the approximate framework of the program I'm trying to use, with all of the error-checking and such removed for readability (I have made sure that all of the calls succeed up until `read()` for both paths)

```
int main(){
  int toChild[2];
  int fromChild[2];
  pipe(toChild);    //Need to make sure both calls to pipe() succeed
  pipe(fromChild);
  int pid = fork(); //Need to make sure pid >= 0
  if(pid == 0){
     close(toChild[1]);
     close(fromChild[0]);
     dup2(toChild[0],STDIN_FILENO);
     close(toChild[0]);
     dup2(fromChild[1],STDOUT_FILENO);
     close(fromChild[1]);
     execl("/usr/bin/cu","cu",arguments...,(char*)NULL);
  }
  else{
     close(toChild[0]);
     close(fromChild[1]);
     char buf[1024];
     ssize_t len = read(fromChild[0],buf,1023); //Need to make sure is not -1
     buf[len] = '\0';
     printf("%s",buf);
     kill(pid,15);
     waitpid(pid,NULL,0);
     close(toChild[1]);
     close(fromChild[0]);
  }
}
```

When I call cu from the command line with the exact arguments I'm using in my `execl()` call, it prints "Connected." and waits, but when I run it via `execl()` the `read()` call hangs until I kill the cu process from another terminal, and after it is killed, the `read()` call succeeds and prints:

```
Connected.
cu: Got termination signal

Disconnected.
```

What is happening? Why is `read()` hung up?

Edit: it may be relevant that I'm using Debian GNU/Linux 10 (Buster)

Comment: I just realized that if I `dup2(fromChild[1],STDERR_FILENO);` instead of `STDOUT_FILENO` "Connected." is carried right through without having to kill cu, but that doesn't explain why the message goes through `STDOUT` when the process is killed. Does `STDERR` get directed to `STDOUT` when processes are killed?

Comment: Are you sure that `read()` happened after the process kill, and it was not that the evidence `printf("%s",buf);` was buffered until the process ended?

Comment: All I know for sure is `read()` was hung up and did not return until cu was killed. I'm not claiming that `read()` definitely happened after the process was killed

Comment: To be sure: add `fflush(stdout);`

Comment: Most likely `cu` is noticing whether or not its stdout is associated with a tty and changing its buffering accordingly.  When it's writing to a tty, it is line buffered, and when it's writing to a pipe it is block buffered.

Comment: What happens when you execute `cu ... | cat`?

Comment: `cu ... | cat` hangs until killed from another terminal, then prints `Connected.\n\tConnected.\n\nDisconnected.` If you'll forgive my c-string notation. I can't really format a comment